# Bus passenger data

Tags: public-transport

I'm looking for a dataset that gives me data on bus passengers. The dataset does not have to come from any specific city or country.

Specifically, I want:

1. Which bus station they depart from
2. Which bus station is their destination station.
3. When they want to arrive at their destination station. Failing that, when they actually do arrive (according, if need be, to bus schedules) at their destination bus station.

Also maybe acceptable:
1) Data on departures from and arrivals to a specific station
2) Number of people in each station at a given time/day.

Comment: Bus entry/exit per passenger with timestamps is going to hard to find - much harder than subway turnstyle counts.

Comment: I get it that you are interested in *Bus* ride data. But still, I like to point out that there exist annual "New York *Taxi* Ride datasets" with >1 million rows each. You can find it on [Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/public-datasets) and in many other places. They are from New York, and also contain dates and times, and "Location IDs" (not coordinates)

Comment: I asked the MTA directly, this was their response: "The MTA does not keep passenger stats in the format you are requesting. If you wish to see the data we have, go to mta.info and look for BusTime info."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on Twitter and got this response:

> Closest you can get AFAIK is the estimated count of people on each vehicle which is available in the real-time feeds.  Unclear how it is calculated or how accurate it is.

[@chris_whong](https://twitter.com/chris_whong/status/1352259400942170112?s=20)

---

https://bt.mta.info/wiki/Developers/Index

specifially: [SIRI for the MTA Bus Time Developer API](https://bt.mta.info/wiki/Developers/SIRIIntro)

The SIRI web service calls implemented by MTA Bus Time are:

- **[VehicleMonitoring](https://bt.mta.info/wiki/Developers/SIRIVehicleMonitoring)**: real-time information about one, many, or all vehicles tracked by the system.
- **[StopMonitoring](https://bt.mta.info/wiki/Developers/SIRIStopMonitoringhttps://bt.mta.info/wiki/Developers/SIRIStopMonitoring)**: real-time information about vehicles serving a particular stop.

---

Requires an API key but is free to use. You'd have to collect data from the API regularly. And you wouldn't know *which* passenger got on/off where.

You can also find some archive data: https://bt.mta.info/wiki/Developers/ArchiveData